# how to get the selected option from ChoiceField in Django Form?

Tags: django, forms, choicefield

i'm working on Forms in Django, i have a choice field which contain a list of continents and i need to work on the selected option 
this is the Select request from my DB:

```
def Select_continent():
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT Continent FROM myform_servercomponents"

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        continents = []
        i=0
        for row in results:
            continents[i]=row[0]
            i+=1
    except:
        print "Error: unable to fetch data"
    db.close()
    return continents
```

and this is my form

```
def continents():
    data = Select_continent()
    i=0
    continents=[]
    for key,value in data:
        continents.append(('i',value))
        i +=1  
    return continents 

class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    Continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=continents())
```

so the question is how can i use the selected option in my view

```
def affiche_all(request, currency):
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                 
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)                                                                                                                                            
        if form.is_valid() : 
            Continent = form.cleaned_data['Continent']
    # here i need to send the selected choice to another view 
    # like this :
    # continent == 'Europe'
    #url = reverse('affiche_all', args=(),   kwargs={'continent': continent})
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

any idea ???

Comment: You can print `form.cleaned_data` and see the data yourself. You can then figure out how to access it. BTW, may I know why aren't you using the Django's ORM and using raw `MySQLdb` cursor?

Comment: What's wrong with your commented-out code? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @bibhas i'm new in django have you a tutorial about Django's ORM ?

Comment: @AmineAntri When learning something new, the first thing you go through is the documentation. Head for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/. Select the right version of Django.